# call a function to terminate php script

Tags: php, function, button, kill

I was wondering if it is possible to call a function to kill the PHP script running, like click on button CANCEL and the function execute.

I tried RESET button but it just removes inputted text/data, even if I stop the page from loading the Apache still executing the script the only way is to stop the Apache itself XAMPP so any help will be appreciated.

```
if(!$handle = fopen($filename, "rb")) {
    die("Unable to open $filename for read! Make sure you edited filesplit.php correctly!<br>");
}

$base_filename = basename($filename);

$piece_name = $targetfolder.'/'.$base_filename.'.'.str_pad($splitnum, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
if(!$fw = fopen($piece_name,"w")) {
    die("Unable to open $piece_name for write. Make sure target folder is writeable.<br>");
}
echo "Splitting $base_filename into $piecesize Mb files <br>"."(last piece may be smaller in size)<br>";
echo "Writing $piece_name<br>";
while (!feof($handle) and $splitnum < 999) {
    if($current < $piece) {
        if($content = fread($handle, $buffer)) {
            if(fwrite($fw, $content)) {
                $current += $buffer;
            } else {
                die("filesplit.php is unable to write to target folder. Target folder may not have write permission! Try chmod +w target_folder<br>");
            }
        }
    } else {
        fclose($fw);
        $current = 0;
        $splitnum++;
        $piece_name = $targetfolder.'/'.$base_filename.'.'.str_pad($splitnum, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        echo "Writing $piece_name...<br>";
        $fw = fopen($piece_name,"w");
    }
}
fclose($fw);
fclose($handle);
echo "Done! <br>";
exit;

function br() {
    return (!empty($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']))?'<br>':"\n";
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about how php works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PemsuAfc7Jw

Comment: until that happen you can help thanks in advance

Comment: @kyo_adam I'm helping you the way you need to be helped of. Learning how php operates (its so simple that its explained that 3 minutes video) you largely improve your vision about it, and thus, your programming will be more easy

Comment: i know and thank you i love php language is there any way to contact you on private please

Comment: sorry, the SO don't offer ways to send/receive private messages. I think theres no problem to post your problems here

Comment: ok how to past my php code here :(

Comment: edit your question and paste your code there

Answer (score 1):

I think you should submit the code first. Anyway i would like to tell you that `die();` is a build in function which kill the all PHP script after calling it.
you may try this. OR please submit you code where you want to RESET.

Comment: die() and exit() yeah but how to do that, i have already a form with a submit button but is it possible to call those functions or other with a click ??

Comment: i have told you to submit the code. without knowing the code how could anyone say what you want to do where you have not specified anything clearly.

Comment: the die() goes on your php script (those lines of code between the `<?php` and `?>`. The click to submit a form will call the action of the form (your form action is `index.php`). So, your index.php file must have a php code that handles submited data